# How to detect input element change when set value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

online code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mb98y/309/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myDirective" ng-controller="x">
    <input id="angular" type="text" ng-model="data.test" my-directive>
</div>
    <button onclick="document.querySelector('#angular').value = 'testg';">click</button>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myDirective', [])
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
                //console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + v);
                alert('value change: ' + scope.data.test);
            });
        }
    };
});

function x($scope) {
    //$scope.test = 'value here';
    $scope.data = {
        test: 'value here'
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mb98y/310/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myDirective" ng-controller="x">
<input id="angular" type="text" my-directive="test">{{test}}</div>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('#angular').value =  'testg';">click</button>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myDirective', [])
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            myDirective: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // set the initial value of the textbox
            element.val(scope.myDirective);
            element.data('old-value', scope.myDirective);

            // detect outside changes and update our input
            scope.$watch('myDirective', function (val) {
                element.val(scope.myDirective);
            });

            // on blur, update the value in scope
            element.bind('propertychange keyup change paste', function (blurEvent) {
                if (element.data('old-value') != element.val()) {
                    console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + element.val());
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.myDirective = element.val();
                        element.data('old-value', element.val());
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

function x($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'value here';
}
```

I wanna click button to set input element value and angularjs(ng-model or scope object) can get it.

But, `document.querySelector('#angular').value =  'testg';`

change element value in this way, Neither angularjs $watch nor bind function can get value change event. If you input some words in input element by keyboard, they both works.

How can I detect input element value change when set value in this way in angularjs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, two-way data binding is here in order to avoid such scenarios.

```
 <input ng-model='ctrl.field' />

 <button ng-click='ctrl.field = "new value"'>change</button>
```

Second, there is `ng-change` directive that works together with `ng-model`, which can be used to do something when value in the model changed.

```
 <input ng-model='ctrl.field' ng-change='alert("changed!")' />
```

If you still want to change value outside of angular directly with DOM, just fire event that angular listen to - `blur` or `keypressed`

```
 <button ng-click='$("#id").val(a); $("#id").trigger("blur")'>change</button>
```

or

```
 <button ng-click='angular.element("#id").val(a); angular.element("#id").trigger("blur")'>change</button>
```

Comment: Good idea for me, the second method fire event works. I followed your suggestion without jquery. Thank you!

Comment: @Gino Angular expose jQuery-lite anyway, so you totally can do it with jquery.

Answer (score 2):

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mb98y/311/).

You are not supposed to use `querySelector` (just like you are not supposed to use jQuery) with Angular, unless you have a real good reason to.

You can just modify `$scope.data.test`, and your text box contents will be updated automatically. In order for this to work, you also need the `button` to have the same controller (so they share scope), and use `ng-click` instead of `onclick`, like so:

```
<div ng-app="myDirective" ng-controller="x">
    <input id="angular" type="text" ng-model="data.test" my-directive=""></input>
    <button ng-click="data.test = 'testg';">click</button>
</div>
```